# Using React context in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I create a simple React context to check if I am connected

```
import NetInfo, { NetInfoState } from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import Constants, { AppOwnership } from 'expo-constants';
import React, { PropsWithChildren, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const ConnectionContext = createContext<boolean>(undefined);

export function ConnectionProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren<any>): JSX.Element {
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);

  function handleConnectionChange(netInfo: NetInfoState) {
    setConnected(
      (Platform.OS === 'ios' && Constants.appOwnership === AppOwnership.Expo) ||
        (netInfo.isConnected && (netInfo.isInternetReachable ?? true))
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptionCancel = NetInfo.addEventListener(handleConnectionChange);
    return () => subscriptionCancel();
  }, []);

  return <ConnectionContext.Provider value={connected}>{children}</ConnectionContext.Provider>;
}

export function useConnection() {
  return useContext(ConnectionContext);
}
```

I was wondering if I want to use it in my existing component `XYZ`, is there a less roundabout way of doing it than the following

From:

```
export function XYZ() {
   ...xyz code...
}
```

to:

```
export function XYZ() {
  return (
    <ConnectionContextProvider>
      <RealXyz>
    </ConnectionContextProvider>
  );
}
function RealXyz() {
  const connected = useConnection();
  ...xyz code...
}
```

Comment: Looking forward the answers to this... but I guess if you need context, it is for globalish state, otherwise you can just `useState` in `XYZ` right? So usually I would assume that the provider will end up wrapping a farther ancestor?

Comment: normally I would, but I needed it just for this one spot.  Because context updates causes rerenders

Comment: No, there is no less roundabout way, although you can implement it as HOC it's not recommended since you already working with function components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think context is really necessary for this since a connection is more of a singleton type of thing. The following code should be in its own file, and you can import this hook anywhere in your app.

```
let _isConnected = false;

export const useConnection = () => {
  const [isConnected, setConnected] = useState(_isConnected);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleConnectionChange(netInfo: NetInfoState) {
      _isConnected =  (Platform.OS === 'ios' && Constants.appOwnership === AppOwnership.Expo) ||
        (netInfo.isConnected && (netInfo.isInternetReachable ?? true))
      
      setConnected(_isConnected);
    }
    
    const subscriptionCancel = NetInfo.addEventListener(handleConnectionChange);

    return () => subscriptionCancel();
  }, []);

  return isConnected;
}
```

Explanation:

Let's say you have two components which use this hook. When your app first renders, only ComponentA is mounted. Some time later the connection state changes to `true`. Then some time later ComponentB is mounted. We want ComponentB to know that the connection state is currently `true`, which is why we use the singleton pattern (eg. private global variable `_isConnected`). It doesn't matter much that there are multiple event listeners as those are cheap and get removed when the component is unmounted.

Comment: You're right, it's should custom hook totally forgot about that.  Also... why not useRef for theisBound? (I am presuming you're using that for checking if the component is mounted.

Also why do you need a _isConnected?

Comment: `useRef` wouldn't work because you'd get a different ref every time you used this hook... hence the singleton pattern.

Comment: I was thinking about the `_isBound` shouldn't that be isMounted as a ref?  But I see what you mean by the "singleton" thingy.  However, I think it's more of an efficiency thing because if we had multiple scoped copies of the ref it should still be fine.

Comment: Oh, crap. I was updating my answer to include an explanation and realized that it didn't work the way I had it. I've updated the code and removed the `_isBound` stuff as it added unnecessary complexity and actually made it not work.

Comment: I think you're right on the first try though you should useRef, because if say you switch to airplane mode in a middle of the switch you can get a situation where you're calling setState with the component that has the hook unmounted.

Comment: `setState` (or `setConnection`) would never get called on an unmounted component because the event listener is removed whenever the component is unmounted. The problem with my initial attempt is that only the first component would get re-rendered whenever the connection state changed.

Answer (score 0):

Context is handy if you have data that needs to be shared across multiple components and you do not want to pass it down the tree by props.

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

In your example I would use `useState`, but to give you a good idea where you could opt for context check the following snippet:

```js
...

function ABC() {
  const connected = useConnection();
  ...abc code...
}

function ABCParent() {
  return <ABC />
}

...

function XYZ() {
  const connected = useConnection();
  ...xyz code...
}

function XYZParent() {
  return <XYZ />
}

...

function App() {
 return (
  <ConnectionContextProvider>
    <ABCParent />
    <XYZParent />
  </ConnectionContextProvider>
 )
}
```

The two components that make use of the context are "deep" in the tree and in separate branches. The example is a bit simple and you could easily pass the data that you need through props and still have a maintainable code base.

But ultimately if you feel that your data model can be "global" and you have enough dependents in separate branches or in the same branch in multiple levels go for context API.

Some data model examples where I find the use of context API useful are theme, app settings, routing and translations.

**One thing to note:** The components that depend on a context will be less reusable (This is more relevant across projects) and sometimes you can opt for composition instead of using the context API. Check the [before you use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) section of the docs for more information about this.